# Set text position exactly

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

```css
.noten_stats {
  height: 200px;
  background: #cc2b5e;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #753a88, #cc2b5e);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #753a88, #cc2b5e);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #ddd;
}

.noten_stats_title {
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Montserrat-Medium;
}

.punkte_container {
  height: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.punkte {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
}

.punkte_text {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Montserrat-Medium;
}
```

```html
<div class='noten_stats'>
  <p class="noten_stats_title">Deine Durchschnittsnote</p>
  <div class="punkte_container">
    <p class="punkte">15</p>
    <p class="punkte_text">Punkte</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result looks like this:
[image: Click to open]

So now I want that the "Punkte" is at the same height as the 15. So that the text "Punkte" aligns at the **bottom** of the "15".

I tried so much but nothing works.

Comment: It would be better if you post the image of the expected result. Bottom of 15 also has a different meaning, like aligning it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.noten_stats {
  height: 200px;
  background: #cc2b5e;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #753a88, #cc2b5e);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #753a88, #cc2b5e);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #ddd;
}

.noten_stats_title {
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Montserrat-Medium;
}

.punkte_container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.punkte {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
}

.punkte_text {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Montserrat-Medium;
}
```

```html
<div class='noten_stats'>
  <p class="noten_stats_title">Deine Durchschnittsnote</p>
  <div class="punkte_container">
    <span class="punkte">15</span>
    <span class="punkte_text">Punkte</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use `span` instead of `p`. It's displaying inline.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `flex-direction: column;` Default is `row` which aligns the text in a horizontal way.

```css
.noten_stats {
  height: 200px;
  background: #cc2b5e;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #753a88, #cc2b5e);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #753a88, #cc2b5e);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #ddd;
}

.noten_stats_title {
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Montserrat-Medium;
}

.punkte_container {
  height: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.punkte {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
}

.punkte_text {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Montserrat-Medium;
}
```

```html
<div class='noten_stats'>
  <p class="noten_stats_title">Deine Durchschnittsnote</p>
  <div class="punkte_container">
    <p class="punkte">15</p>
    <p class="punkte_text">Punkte</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add:

```
align-self: center;
```

to .punkte_text:

```
.punkte_text {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Montserrat-Medium;
  align-self: center;
}
```